# Regular Expression to extract function arguments in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a problem to extract function arguments in R.

```
    x="theme(legend.position='bottom', 
    legend.margin=(t=0,r=0,b=0,l=0,unit='mm'), 
    legend.background=element_rect(fill='red',size=rel(1.5)), 
    panel.background=element_rect(fill='red'),
    legend.position='bottom')"
```

What I want is:

```
[1]legend.position='bottom'
[2]legend.margin=(t=0,r=0,b=0,l=0,unit='mm')
[3]legend.background=element_rect(fill='red',size=rel(1.5))
[4]panel.background=element_rect(fill='red')
[5]legend.position='bottom'
```

I tried several regular expressions without success including followings:

`strsplit(x,",(?![^()]*\\))",perl=TRUE)`

Please help me!

Comment: I'll take you back a step. How did you end up with R/ggplot code saved as text? I'm guessing there has to be an easier way to do this in the first place..

Comment: Actually I am making a shiny godget to teach ggplot2. I will make this shiny app into an RStudio addin package and release on CRAN within a couple of days.

Comment: i'm trying, but it's kinda complex

Comment: A regex really isn't the best thing to use in this case.  In general, you need formal parser here, because you have nested parentheses.  In fact, the R interpreter itself will use a parser each time you make this actual function call.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I know it's not but this kind of question (parsing arbitrary arguments) has been asked on SO so many times before. In the end, it all comes down to: *Regular expression - while powerful - are not made for this kind of task.*

Comment: @Jan I posted an answer.  I've never written a parser in R (though I have in Java and JavaScript).  Agreed.  Even if the regex answer below works here, if the OP has more nested depth the regex would break later on.

Comment: `ggraptr` might be useful. https://github.com/cargomoose/ggraptR

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer here might be to *not* attempt to use a regex to parse your function call.  As the name implies, regular expressions require regular language.  Your function call is not regular, because it has nested parentheses.  I currently see a max nested depth of two, but who knows if that could get deeper at some point.

I would recommend writing a simple parser instead.  You can use a stack here, to keep track of parentheses.  And you would only split a parameter off if all parentheses were closed, implying that you are not in the middle of a parameter, excepting possibly the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

Arf, I'm really sorry but i have to go work, i will continue later but for now i just let my way to solve it partially : `theme\(([a-z.]*=['a-z]*)|([a-z._]*=[a-z0-9=,'_.()]*)*\,\)?`

It misses only the last part..

Here the regex101 page : https://regex101.com/r/BZpcW0/2

See you later.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your advice. I have parsed the sentences and get the arguments as list. Here is my solution.

```
x<-"theme(legend.margin=margin(t=0,r=0,b=0,l=0,unit='mm'),
legend.background=element_rect(fill='red',size=rel(1.5)),
panel.background=element_rect(fill='red'),
legend.position='bottom')" 

extractArgs=function(x){

result<-tryCatch(eval(parse(text=x)),error=function(e) return("error"))

if("character" %in% class(result)){
    args=character(0)
} else {
    if(length(names(result)>0)){
       pos=unlist(str_locate_all(x,names(result)))
       pos=c(sort(pos[seq(1,length(pos),by=2)]),nchar(x)+1)

       args=c()
       for(i in 1:(length(pos)-1)){
         args=c(args,substring(x,pos[i],lead(pos)[i]-2))
       } 

  } else{
      args=character(0)
  }
}
args
}
```